# Strange result in python

Tags: python, string, identity

Could someone explain me this strange result on python 2.6.6 ?

```
>>> a = "xx"
>>> b = "xx"
>>> a.__hash__() == b.__hash__()
True
>>> a is b
True # ok.. was just to be sure

>>> a = "x" * 2
>>> b = "x" * 2
>>> a.__hash__() == b.__hash__()
True
>>> a is b
True # yeah.. looks ok so far !

>>> n = 2
>>> a = "x" * n
>>> b = "x" * n
>>> a.__hash__() == b.__hash__()
True # still okay..
>>> a is b
False # hey! What the F... ?
```

Comment: Where the heck do people learn about `is`, but not about how it's different from `==`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python '==' vs 'is' comparing strings, 'is' fails sometimes, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

Comment: @SilentGhost: Not exactly, since this touches on the topic of when compilers might intern strings unexpectedly.

Comment: @Glenn: *unexpectedly*? what are you on about? and I was first to admit that it's not the closest dupe, but there are still many exactly same discussions on SO.

Comment: @SilentGhost: "On about"?  I guarantee that 98% of Python programmers wouldn't expect "'n' * 2" to be interned by the compiler, since the Python compiler doesn't perform very many optimizations.

Comment: @Glenn: not very many, but the string optimization it is known for :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To understand this, you need to understand a few different things.

- `a is b` returns true if `a` and `b` are *the same object*, not merely if they have *the same value*.  Strings can have the same value but be a different instance of that value.
- When you say `a = "x"`, what you're actually doing is creating a string constant `"x"` and then assigning a name to it, `a`.  String *constants* are strings which are written literally in the code, and not calculated programmatically.  String constants are always *interned*, which means they're stored in a table for reuse: if you say `a = "a"; b = "a"`, it's actually the same as saying `a = "a"; b = a`, as they'll use the same interned string `"a"`.  That's why the first `a is b` is True.
- When you say `a = "x" * 2`, the Python compiler is actually optimizing this.  It calculates the string at compile-time--it generates code *as if* you had written `a = "xx"`.  Thus, the resulting string `"xx'` is interned.  That's why the second `a is b` is true.
- When you say `a = "x" * n`, the Python compiler *doesn't know what n is* at compile time.  Therefore, it's forced to actually output the string `"x"` and then perform the string multiplication at runtime.  Since that's performed at runtime, while `"x"` is interned the resulting string `"xx"` is *not*.  As a result, each of these strings are different instances of `"xx"`, so the final `a is b` is False.

You can see the difference yourself:

```
def a1():
    a = "x"
def a2():
    a = "x" * 2
def a3():
    n = 2
    a = "x" * n


import dis
print "a1:"
dis.dis(a1)

print "a2:"
dis.dis(a2)

print "a3:"
dis.dis(a3)
```

In CPython 2.6.4, this outputs:

```
a1:
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
a2:
  6           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('xx')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
a3:
  8           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (n)

  9           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('x')
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
             12 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             13 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Finally, note that you can say `a = intern(a); b = intern(b)` to create interned versions if the strings, which will guarantee that `a is b` is true.  If all you want is to check string equality, however, just use `a == b`.

Comment: About intern, I found the strings lower or equal than 20 char length are automaticaly interned by Python. 
My real question was, why "x"*2 (interned) was different than "x"*n.. (not interned, even if n <= 20)

Answer (score 18):

The `is` operator tells you whether two variables **point to the same object in memory**. It is rarely useful and often confused with the `==` operator, which tells you whether two objects "look the same".

It is particularly confusing when used with things like short string literals, because the Python compiler interns these for efficiency. In other words, when you write `"xx"` the compiler (emits bytecode that) creates one string object in memory and causes all literals `"xx"` to point to it. This explains why your first two comparisons are True. Notice that you can get the id of the strings by calling `id` on them, which (at least on CPython is probably) their address in memory:

```
>>> a = "xx"
>>> b = "xx"
>>> id(a)
38646080
>>> id(b)
38646080
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = "x"*10000
>>> b = "x"*10000
>>> id(a)
38938560
>>> id(b)
38993504
>>> a is b
False
```

The third is because the compiler hasn't interned the strings `a` and `b`, for whatever reason (probably because it isn't smart enough to notice that the variable `n` is defined once and then never modified).

You can in fact force Python to intern strings by, well, [asking it to](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#intern). This will give you a piddling amount of performance increase and might help. It's probably useless.

Moral: don't use `is` with string literals. Or int literals. Or anywhere you don't mean it, really.

Comment: It would be worth adding an explanation of why the first two `a is b` calls work.

Comment: And if you want to further inspect, test out the results of `id(a)` and `id(b)` for the three cases.

Comment: *for whatever reason*. well the reason is quite obvious, isn't it? because compiler doesn't produce byte code for those n-long strings.

Comment: @Glenn: variations of this question were answered many times over. The dupe I'm suggesting probably is not the closest one, but there is a handful of discussion out there re the topic.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Not really what I mean.  I'm just irked by this 2-minute quick-and-obvious answer being voted up to 10, while the 10-minute detailed answer (which, I suspect, points out a detail of the Python compiler that most people probably didn't know about) gets largely ignored.  It's a common issue on the site: people are more likely to vote a question up if it's already been voted up.

Comment: I would definitely *not* say that `is` "is rarely useful."

Comment: Strings bigger than 20 chars lenght are not automatically interned (20 is the value I found on my python 2.6.6, may vary on your config?), so it's normal that "x"*10000  is not interned..  

My question was why there is difference between the two ways x"*2 and "x"*n (with n=2, of course)